# How to make organisation chart by getting data from mysql and php

Tags: orgchart

I want to show my data on balkan graph by php which is stored in mysql . Have enyone any idea that how to create ID and PID dynamically.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

BALKANGraph developer evangelist here

If you have unique filed in your data, for example email address or telephone number, you can use that field as id or pid